# FBXLoader: I can't load more than one object

Tags: three.js, loader, fbx

I am just trying to follow examples and get myself putting my own models into a scene. However, when using the FBXLoader, I'm not sure what if what I'm doing is right. I can only get one FBX to load at a time. I'm not a coder first, so sorry if my code looks sloppy:

I have an object called range_burners.fbx. It loads in fine by itself. I have a model called range_main.fbx that works just fine by itself. But both of them together, well the range_main.fbx always seems to take precedent.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0022)http://127.0.0.1:1024/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>three.js webgl - FBX loader</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a {
                color: #046;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
            <a href="http://threejs.org/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> - FBXLoader<br>
            Character and animation from <a href="https://www.mixamo.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Mixamo</a>
        </div>

        <script src="./index_files/three.js.download"></script>

        <script src="./index_files/inflate.min.js.download"></script>
        <script src="./index_files/FBXLoader.js.download"></script>

        <script src="./index_files/OrbitControls.js.download"></script>

        <script src="./index_files/Detector.js.download"></script>
        <script src="./index_files/stats.min.js.download"></script>

        <script>

            if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

            var container, stats, controls;
            var camera, scene, renderer, light;

            var clock = new THREE.Clock();

            var mixers = [];

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.set( 100, 200, 300 );

                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                controls.target.set( 0, 100, 0 );
                controls.update();

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xa0a0a0 );
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xa0a0a0, 200, 1000 );

                light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0x444444 );
                light.position.set( 0, 200, 0 );
                scene.add( light );

                light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
                light.position.set( 0, 200, 100 );
                light.castShadow = true;
                light.shadow.camera.top = 180;
                light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
                light.shadow.camera.left = -120;
                light.shadow.camera.right = 120;
                scene.add( light );

                // scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( light.shadow.camera ) );

                // ground
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 2000, 2000 ), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x999999, depthWrite: false } ) );
                mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                scene.add( mesh );

                var grid = new THREE.GridHelper( 2000, 20, 0x000000, 0x000000 );
                grid.material.opacity = 0.2;
                grid.material.transparent = true;
                scene.add( grid );

                var burners = new THREE.FBXLoader();
                burners.load( '/fbx/range_burners.fbx', function ( object ) {
                    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if( child.material ) {
                            child.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ( {
                                color: 0x151515,
                                metalness: 0.8,
                                roughness: 0.6

                            } );
                        }
                    } )
                    object.position.set(0, 200, 0);
                    scene.add ( object );
                } );

                // model
                var range = new THREE.FBXLoader();
                range.load( '/fbx/range_main.fbx', function ( object2 ) {
                    object2.traverse( function ( child2 ) {
                        if( child2.material ) {
                            child2.material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial ( {
                                color: 0xffffff,
                                metalness: 0.8,
                                roughness: 0.4
                            } );
                        }
                    } )
                    object2.position.set(-150, 0, 0);
                    scene.add ( object2 );
                } );

                //burners




                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                // stats
                stats = new Stats();
                container.appendChild( stats.dom );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                if ( mixers.length > 0 ) {

                    for ( var i = 0; i < mixers.length; i ++ ) {

                        mixers[ i ].update( clock.getDelta() );

                    }

                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

                stats.update();

            }

        </script><div><canvas width="1920" height="898" style="width: 1920px; height: 898px;"></canvas><div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.9; z-index: 10000;"><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: block;"></canvas><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: none;"></canvas><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: none;"></canvas></div></div><div><canvas width="928" height="898" style="width: 928px; height: 898px;"></canvas><div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; cursor: pointer; opacity: 0.9; z-index: 10000;"><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: block;"></canvas><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: none;"></canvas><canvas width="80" height="48" style="width: 80px; height: 48px; display: none;"></canvas></div></div>




</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty good. It's not obvious to me why one would override the other, unless perhaps its hidden behind the other one?
Might try moving their initial positions?

Also, you probably want to do your THREE.WebGLRenderer initialization before you fire off the loaders.. i.e. put your loaders at the end of the init...
Another way to debug is to set 'wireframe:true" on your materials, so you can see of one of them is hiding inside the other...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have several times moved the initial positioning and it doesn't seem to help. I've definitely moved it out of the area, either above or below, the larger unit (the main part of the stove). However! I have not tried to do the THREE.WEBGLRenderer initialization and I will also check wireframes and I'll get back to you. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: so I reorganized, set wireframe, etc. The other model definitely will not load when the range_main is loaded.

Comment: Ok. 2 options.. make a working fiddle and we can try and debug it.. or drop into our slack channel where some of us hang out and try to help people, and we might be able to talk you through it...
https://join.slack.com/t/threejs/shared_invite/enQtMzYxMzczODM2OTgxLWE5OTU4OTYxZTZlODk1ZGNjODIyMDZlODM4ZmUyMzNiOWIxMmFjNTYwOTc4MjU0ZmNiODk5MzZiMGJhMTkzZWI

Comment: @ScottRinehart I am using FBXLoader in a different scenario and may be encountering the same issue that you did. I wanted to check in with you to see if you have progressed on it?